# How to use "Distinct" in query expression for Entity object

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework-6, query-expressions

I am writing a query to a entity object, is it possible to use  distinct on a column ? below is my query

```
  query = From r In objEntity.W_PDD
           Join p In objEntity.W_PER
           On r.PER_NO Equals p.PER_NO
            Where p.RECEIVED_DATE = DateTime.Today
            Order By r.PER_NO Select r
```

Comment: Nope I have tried it that did not work and I also tried using the Distinct inside the query that too did not work. query = (From r in ......... Distinct Select r)

Comment: What exactly do you want to be distinct?  Is there a one to many relationship to W_PER?  You probably will be fine with a group by, but hard to say without details of your data model.

Comment: please give example of current output and desired output.

Comment: If you want Distinct on certain column, best thing you can do is GroupBy that column, followed by `Select(r => r.FirstOrDefault()`